# Getting nulls on executing Stored Procedure in web api but getting result in MSSQL

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a stored procedure that gives me this output in MSSql Server
[image]

So I created a class to catch this output like so:

```
public class OwnerInfo
{
    public string UnitName { get; set; }
    public string UnitOwner { get; set; }
}
public class FirstInfo
{
    public string TType { get; set; }
    public string TransactionType { get; set; }
    public string Period_Covered { get; set; }
    public double? BillAmount { get; set; }
    public double? PaymentAmount { get; set; }
    public double? Balance { get; set; }
}
public class SecondInfo
{
    public string TType { get; set; }
    public string TransactionType { get; set; }
    public string Period { get; set; }
    public double? BillAmount { get; set; }
    public double? PaymentAmount { get; set; }
    public double? Balance { get; set; }
}
public class ThirdInfo
{
    public string TType { get; set; }
    public string TransactionType { get; set; }
    public string Period { get; set; }
    public double? PaymentAmount { get; set; }
}
public class FourthInfo
{
    public string TType { get; set; }
    public string Particulars { get; set; }
    public string PaymentDate { get; set; }
    public double? PaymentAmount { get; set; }
    public string ORNumber { get; set; }
}
public class DisplaySoa
{
    public OwnerInfo OwnerInfo { get; set; }
    public List<FirstInfo> FirstInfo { get; set; }
    public List<SecondInfo> SecondInfo { get; set; }
    public List<ThirdInfo> ThirdInfo { get; set; }
    public List<FourthInfo> FourthInfo { get; set; }
}
public class DisplaySoaParameter
{
    public int UnitID { get; set; }
    public int Month { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
}
```

And the way I get it from the database is in my controller and I call the stored procedure like so:

```
const string query = "[dbo].[DISPLAY_SOA_V4] @UnitID, @Month, @Year";
            using(var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {

                try
                {
                    //const string query = "[dbo].[DUES_AUTO_PAYMENT] @PaymentAmount @PaymentTypeID @ORNumber @UnitID @CurrentDateTime";
                    object[] parameter =
                    {
                        new SqlParameter
                        {
                            ParameterName = "@UnitID",
                            Value = model.UnitID,
                            Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                            SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int
                        },
                        new SqlParameter
                        {
                            ParameterName = "@Month",
                            Value = model.Month,
                            Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                           SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int
                        },
                        new SqlParameter
                        {
                            ParameterName = "@Year",
                            Value = model.Year,
                            Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                            SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int
                        }
                    };

                    var x = db.Database.SqlQuery<DisplaySoa>(query, parameter).ToList();
                    return x;
                }
                catch (Exception ed)
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
```

but in my "x" value I get null like so:
[image]

That image is when I use .FirstOrDefault() bur if I use .ToList(), I get a count of 1 but nothing is insede i .Can you please help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: have a look here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/designer/advanced/multiple-result-sets

Comment: It would be awesome if you could include the definition of your stored proc in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sp is returning multiple result sets.

```
var x = db.Database.SqlQuery<DisplaySoa>(query, parameter).ToList();
```

From this you can't handle that.

Please read [this](https://www.khalidabuhakmeh.com/entity-framework-6-multiple-result-sets-with-stored-procedures) article for how to do that.

Comment: Than you for that answer. I still have some issues like this one: 'An error occurred accessing the database. This usually means that the connection to the database failed. Check that the connection string is correct and that the appropriate DbContext constructor is being used to specify it or find it in the application's config file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=386386 for information on DbContext and connections. See the inner exception for details of the failure.' but I guess I should ask another question for it.